# Make div keyboard-scrollable in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, scroll, focus, overflow

From what I can tell, although jQuery-Mobile-powered pages can contain divs with overflow set to scroll or auto, and these divs can be scrolled with the one-screen bar or the mouse wheel, they cannot be scrolled using the arrow keys, page-up/page-down, or home/end.

Instead, the official "page" div (with data-role="page") absorbs all this input. Perhaps other divs can't even acquire focus, I'm not sure.

Is there any way around this?

EDIT: JSfiddle of simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/qogz0shx/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>

<style>
    #outer {
        overflow:scroll;
        height: 50vh;
        width: 50vw;
    }

    #inner {
        height: 500vh;
        width: 500vw;
    }
</style>

<div data-role="page">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same example without the external files: https://jsfiddle.net/xr0hjjjc/

```
<style>
    #outer {
        overflow:scroll;
        height: 50vh;
        width: 50vw;
    }

    #inner {
        height: 500vh;
        width: 500vw;
    }
</style>

<div data-role="page">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome, if you click on the div in the second example and press the arrow keys, you should see the scroll bars move. If you do the same with the first one, they won't.

Comment: Could you provide a specific example with code, what you've tried so far? A JSFiddle (or similar) with your example would be nice to help.

Comment: Added an example of the issue in its most basic form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On revisiting this with new searches ("focus" is a better keyword here than "scroll"), I discovered a *much* simpler solution.

Just give the div in question a tabindex attribute, to make it focus-able. Make the value -1 so it won't interfere with the tabindex of anything else. (This means that if the user keeps pressing tab, the div in question will never be focused. Change the index to a positive number if you want it to be focus-able that way).

```
<div id="outer" tabindex="-1"> </div>
<!-- Containing element with overflow:scroll or whatever -->
```

and that's it. Once the div is clicked it should override whatever jQuery Mobile does to prohibit focus. New JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/romqveLn/).

Answer (score 1):

You're right, internal `<div>`s cannot be scrolled using keyboard. My approach to this limitation is simple:

- create new handler for up/down/PageUp/PageDown keys
- when those keys are pressed, get element under mouse
- if the element contains the `keyboardScroll` class, scroll it accordingly

So, mouse position sets which element has to be scrolled.

**Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qogz0shx/2/)** (*click* to focus the "run" quadrant before scrolling)

**JavaScript**

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

$(document).on("pageinit", "#page", function(event)
{
    $(document).mousemove(function(event)
    {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    });

    // keyboard handler
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e)
    {
        // get element under mouse
        var element = document.elementFromPoint(currentMousePos.x, currentMousePos.y);

        // search for scrollable element in parents
        while (!$(element).hasClass("keyboardScroll") && $(element).parents().length !== 0)
            element = element.parentElement;

        if (!$(element).hasClass("keyboardScroll"))
            return; // no scrollable element found

        // set scroll "speed"
        var delta = 10;

        if (e.keyCode === 38) // up
            delta *= -1;
        else if (e.keyCode === 40) // down
            delta *= 1;
        else if (e.keyCode === 33) // pageup
            delta *= -10;
        else if (e.keyCode === 34) // pagedown
            delta *= 10;
        else
            return;

        // scroll element
        $(element).scrollTop($(element).scrollTop() + delta);

        // stop event from propagating to jQuery Mobile handlers
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```